# Git global core.fileMode false overridden locally on clone

Tags: git, config

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes), I was able to configure both globally and locally my `fileMode` config to false.

However, when I `git clone`, git keeps initializing the projects with local config forced to `fileMode true`, so that it overrides my global `false`. As a consequence I have, for every project, to either remove the local config or set it to `false` manually, which entirely lose the point of having a global config.

How can I prevent git from setting, by default, on every project, this config locally? Is that driven by another config variable? By the server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clone, like init, always sets a local `core.filemode` when it creates a new repository.  See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376913/1256452) for details.  The only way to clobber the local setting after a clone is to do it manually (e.g., by having a wrapper command that does the clone, then goes into the clone and removes the setting).  Or, as in [tst's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35630819/1256452) and [Steve Benner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392318/git-global-core-filemode-false-overridden-locally-on-clone#comment99321376_30394903), add `-c core.filemode=false` to your `git clone` (be sure to put the `-c` option *after* the verb `clone`).

Comment: Hey =) Thanks for your answer. "*Clone, like init, always sets a local `core.filemode` when it creates a new repository*". And there is realy no way at all to configure the fact that it sets that fileMode ? =/

Comment: @CyrilCHAPON: there is a build-time option (again, see other answer), so you could tweak your build.  The option makes this a little easier than just modifying the source, but not a lot easier. :-)

Comment: Got it, thanks. Shame the way its designed but you answer my question

Comment: I'm also sad and confused as to why `git init` overrides the global setting... An example of a 'wrapper command' would be a Bash function like `ginit() { git init --config core.filemode=false; }` **or** a shell alias, such as `alias ginit="git init --config core.filemode=false"` (I would not recommend overriding the original command itself with an alias)

Comment: @SteveBenner: the *why* is that the core developers of Git intended (and presumably still intend) `core.fileMode` to reflect a property of the file system itself, rather than a user-chosen setting. I'm not at all sure I *agree* with the core developers, but that would be *why* they did it.

Answer (score 11):

```
git clone --config core.filemode=false YOUR_REPOSITORY
```

for further information refer to the usage information of git clone, or just enter:

```
git clone
```

without any arguments