# Git clone without needing chmod rights

Tags: git, chmod

I am a storage administrator, and due to various issues in the past we are trying to take the ability to edit file permissions away from users. Our shares are SMB running NTFS perms, and we hand out Modify permissions to users as they desire. We want to avoid handing out the Full permissions that would let permissions be changed.

However this is running face first into our developers running git clone, which appears to be trying to run chmod on a .lock file.

Based on [this KB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392318/git-global-core-filemode-false-overridden-locally-on-clone) we have tried adding the arguments --config core.filemode=false to the git clone command with no change in behavior.

I know *why* this is happening, and if I handout full rights this will work. My question is "Is there a set of arguments we can pass with git clone that would prevent it from trying to alter the permissions on the lock or other component files"

Thanks! (If it matters the end user is running git on a mac)

[CHMOD Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tHpC.png)

Comment: Your only option at this point is to build a private version of Git that doesn't even attempt the `chmod` call. (Well, that, or change how you manage the storage here. You might consider giving users their own "disk drives" via iSCSI or similar.)

Comment: Trying to understand your setup : users are still allowed to create files ? the access rights they choose on creation become permanent ?

Comment: @LeGEC they have NTFS rights to create / modify etc, but the perms inherit from root, all AD group based perms.

Comment: @torek thanks for the info, thats a bridge too far for our level of operational maturity, so it looks like we are handing out full rights. Appreciate your insight!