# Git see other file permssion than my filesystem

Tags: git

In git bash for windows 10 when I do:

```
$ ls -la
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 1049089   10 Jul 23 19:00 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user 1049089   28 Sep 19 15:47 a.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user 1049089   28 Sep 19 15:47 b.sh*
```

I can see that both `a.sh` and `b.sh` are executable. Also I have verified that by running both scripts - so from my filesystem point of view both of those files are executable.

But when I do:

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob c91cb20899da1dc6da1752f8b9cdc59e58e50873    a.sh
100755 blob c91cb20899da1dc6da1752f8b9cdc59e58e50873    b.sh
```

So from git perspective only `b.sh` is executable which is also the case when I clone my repository on jenkins an try to execute the two scripts (only `b.sh` is getting executed).

I have tried to: `chmod +x a.sh` but git does not pick that up and just returns a status saying nothing to commit or nothing has been modified.

What is going on and how do I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I now have:

```
$ git config -l | grep core
core.symlinks=true
core.autocrlf=false
core.fscache=true
core.editor='C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
core.editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession
core.autocrlf=false
core.preloadindex=true
core.fscache=true
core.filemode=true
```

Which makes sense since I have added `core.filemode=true` in `C:\Users\user\.gitconfig`:

```
...
[core]
    editor = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession
    autocrlf = false
    preloadindex = true
    fscache = true
    fileMode = true
...
```

But when I clone a new repository and run the same again from *inside* the repository I get:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@host/my-repo.git
..
$ cd my-repo
$ git config -l | grep core
core.symlinks=true
core.autocrlf=false
core.fscache=true
core.editor='C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
core.editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession
core.autocrlf=false
core.preloadindex=true
core.fscache=true
core.filemode=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
```

So it now lists two entries for `core.filemode`. First one I guess is from the .gitconfig file from my user folder and the second one (set to false) seems to come from the file `my-repo/.git/config` that contains:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
```

What determines what gets set in `my-repo/.git/config` and why is that set to false?

Based on:

[Git global core.fileMode false overridden locally on clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392318/git-global-core-filemode-false-overridden-locally-on-clone)

and:

[Git ignoring gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376913/git-ignoring-gitconfig/10377092?noredirect=1#comment102439400_10377092)

it seem I need to manully change .git/config after a clone for it to have any effect.

Comment: I don't have time to read through it right now, but it looks like this might be helpful https://medium.com/@tahteche/how-git-treats-changes-in-file-permissions-f71874ca239d

Comment: A few ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580596/7976758: what is your `git config core.fileMode`? Try `git diff --summary | grep 'mode change`. Try `git update-index --chmod=+x a.sh`. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+executable

Answer (score 1):

You set the `core.fileMode` to `true` on Windows so git will track the execution bit

```
# tell git to keep/ignore filemode (chmod) as change,
git config core.fileMode true/false
```

> ***`core.fileMode`***
> Tells Git if the executable bit of files in the working tree is to be honored.
> The default is true (when core.filemode is not specified in the config file).

---

#### ***`How to update executable bit?` (as you already did)***

```
# If you wish to set the executable bit use this command
git update-index --chmod=+x <file>
```

> ***`--chmod=(+|-)x`***
> Set the execute permissions on the updated files.

Comment: See my updated post, it seem that core.fileMode is forced to false in the local gitconfig file for some reason.